# Tornado / Flask not responding correctly to OPTIONS

Tags: python, http, http-headers, flask, tornado

I have a Flask application that is running on a Tornado web server. I would like to be able to call OPTIONS from the client. I'll admit I'm not 100% which is the best way to go about this. I found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/), and put it into my flask application. This worked on the development server (Flask only) for all requests except `OPTIONS`. When I sat the application on Tornado I added this to my tornado application:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept")
```

This returns the following header for all requests except `OPTIONS`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:CONTENT-TYPE, AUTHORIZATION, ACCEPT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:21600
Content-Length:3493
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Server:TornadoServer/3.1
```

But `OPTIONS` just returns:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Allow: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
Server: TornadoServer/3.1
```

What does it take to return the full header to `OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking out the `BaseHandler` class and setting `provide_automatic_options` to `False` in the decorator and that works.